# org.hibernate.InstantiationException: How to tell Hibernate which class to use for object instantiation

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, subclass

I am currently trying to replace my own database controller implementation with Hibernate and I have the following problem creating an appropriate mapping file.

(I am very new to Hibernate, so please be gentle :-) - I've read through the whole Hibernate Reference documentation but I don't have any practical experience yet).

(The whole thing should represent the relationship between email accounts and their server settings).

I have a class called MailAccount which has 2 properties (see code below):

```
public class MailAccount{
    long id;
    IncomingMailServer  incomingServer;
    OutgoingMailServer  outgoingServer;

    public MailAccount(){
        super();
    }

    // Getter and setter omitted
}
```

The server class hierachy looks like this:

**MailServer.java**

```
public abstract class MailServer {
    String password;
    String host;
    String username;
    String port;

    // Getter and setter omitted
}
```

**IncomingMailServer.java**

```
public abstract class IncomingMailServer extends MailServer {
}
```

**OutgoingMailServer.java**

```
public abstract class OutgoingMailServer extends MailServer {
}
```

**Pop3Server.java**

```
public class Pop3Server extends IncomingMailServer{
    public Pop3Server(){
        super();
    }
}
```

**ImapServer.java**

```
public class ImapServer extends IncomingMailServer{
    public ImapServer(){
        super();
    }
}
```

**SmtpServer.java**

```
public class SmtpServer extends OutgoingMailServer{
    public SmtpServer(){
        super();
    }
}
```

The properties incomingServer and outgoingServer in MailAccount.java of course only hold instances of either Pop3Server, ImapServer (for incomingServer) or SmtpServer (for outgoingServer).

Now, I tried to create the mapping file for MailAccount:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="test.account">
    <class name="MailAccount" table="MAILACCOUNTS" dynamic-update="true">

        <id name="id" column="MAIL_ACCOUNT_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <component name="incomingServer" class="test.server.incoming.IncomingMailServer">
            <property name="password" column="INCOMING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="host" column="INCOMING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="username" column="INCOMING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="port" column="INCOMING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
        </component>

        <component name="outgoingServer" class="test.server.outgoing.OutgoingMailServer">
            <property name="password" column="OUTGOING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="host" column="OUTGOING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="username" column="OUTGOING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
            <property name="port" column="OUTGOING_SERVER_PASSWORD" />
        </component>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Note:** Since I got a 1:1 relation between MailAccount and IncomingMailServer as well as MailAccount and OutgoingMailServer, I want everything in 1 table in order to prevent unnecessary joins.

**The problem:** Whenever I tell Hibernate to save an instance of MailAccount, like this:

```
session = getSession();
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.save(mailAccount);
transaction.commit();
```

.. I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException:
>   Cannot instantiate abstract class or
>   interface:
>   test.server.incoming.IncomingMailServer

This totally makes sense since abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

However, **here comes my question**: How can I tell Hibernate to create an instance of the right class (Pop3Server, SmtpServer, ImapServer) instead of the abstract ones?

**Example:** If the property incomingServer holds an instance of Pop3Server, then Hiberante should store that into my database and when I load the according MailAccount back, I want Hibernate to recreate an instance of Pop3Server.

Comment: Are you creating a new database or mapping to an existing one?  If so we'd need to know what's in the actual tables.  Normally when you have a table that holds more than one type of Entity you have a DiscriminatorColumn on it that tells hibernate which concrete class to use, but tmk you can't do that for a component.

Comment: I think Affe is right, not sure there is a way to do this via components. And anyway, it really is odd to use 1 table to represent all these concepts. It's better to have a MailAccounts table that has it's own id and either multiple foreign key columns to the MailServers tables, or a 1-many relation with the MailServers table with a type column indicating IN, OUT, whatever else

Comment: @Affe I let Hibernate create the tables by setting <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

Comment: @Java Drinker I know that it might sound strange to do all this in just one table but as I mentioned in my original post, I wanted to minimize the number of joins between tables in order to boost performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is occurring because a component is not a stand-alone entity, but "`a class whose instances are stored as an intrinsic part of an owning entity and share the identity of the entity`".  In JPA terms it is considered an [Embeddable](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_JPA_%28ELUG%29#Embeddable) class.  These classes are usually used to create a class object out of a number of table columns that would normally have to be stored as individual attributes in an entity (you can almost look at it as grouping).

While there are a number of benefits to this approach, there are some restrictions.  One of these restrictions are that the component or embeddable cannot be an abstract class.  The reason being that there isn't any way for hibernate to associate a particular concrete subclass with the value you are trying to store or read.  Think of it this way: would you be able to tell what instance to create by only looking at the column data? It's usually not that straight forward, especially for the persistence engine.

In order to get the functionality you desire, you will want to look into storing MailServer data as a separate entity with its own primary key field.  Doing so allows you to manage the data with subclasses using various inheritance methods such as including a DiscriminatorColumn or separate tables (depending on your configuration).

Here are some links that should help you with setting up these mappings and using entity inheritance:

- [One-to-One mapping example](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html)
  (useful if not reusing `MailServer`
  data.
- [Inheritance overview](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)
- [Useful Hibernate examples (not
  latest spec, but gives you good
  overview)](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-example.html)

Hope this helps.

http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-example.html

If you were to use this approach using Hibernate (I personally prefer JPA-based Annotation configurations), you could configure `MailServer` as an abstract entity that would define the common column mappings between the classes and a DiscriminatorColumn (if using same table inheritance).  The subclasses would be built off of this definition, adding custom attributes as needed.